# Converting transfer function to cascaded IIR filter

Tags: filter-design, infinite-impulse-response, digital-filters

I have two function, But I don't know which one is correct to convert my Transfer Function(tf) to secound order sections(sos).

I'm using GNU octave, and it have intrinsic `tf2cas`, also in [github](https://github.com/sonientaegi/matlab/blob/master/DSP/dir2cas.m) function `dir2cas`is existing. I wonder to use which, since they have different response.

Octave intrinsic `tf2cas` weirdly does not use `poly` to reconstruct the polynomials of sos. But github code `dir2cas` uses that!

Here is the response:

> ```
> >> [sos,g]=tf2sos([1 .8 0 0 0 1],[1 0 .2 0 0 .9]) sos =
>
>    1.0000   0.9364   1.0228   1.0000   0.5772   1.0263
>    1.0000  -1.3693   0.7930   1.0000  -1.5171   0.9329
>         0   1.0000   1.2329        0   1.0000   0.9400
>
> g = 1
> >> [b0,B,A]=dir2cas([1 .8 0 0 0 1],[1 0 .2 0 0 .9]) b0 = 1 B =
>
>    1.0000   0.9364   1.0228
>    1.0000  -1.3693   0.7930
>    1.0000   1.2329        0
>
> A =
>
>    1.0000   0.5772   1.0263
>    1.0000  -1.5171   0.9329
>    1.0000   0.9400        0
> ```

### Note:

output format of `tf2sos`: [b01 b11 b21; a01 a11 a21; b11 b21 ...]

`tf2sos.m`:

```
function [b0,B,A] = dir2cas(b,a);

% DIRECT-form to CASCADE-form conversion (cplxpair version)

% ---------------------------------------------------------

% [b0,B,A] = dir2cas(b,a)
% b0 = gain coefficient
%  B = K by 3 matrix of real coefficients containing bk's
%  A = K by 3 matrix of real coefficients containing ak's
%  b = numerator polynomial coefficients of DIRECT form
%  a = denominator polynomial coefficients of DIRECT form
if size(a,1)>size(a,2)
  a=a.';
  b=b.';
endif

% compute gain coefficient b0

b0 = b(1); b = b/b0;
a0 = a(1); a = a/a0;
b0 = b0/a0;

%

M = length(b); N = length(a);
if N > M
    b = [b zeros(1,N-M)];
elseif M > N
    a = [a zeros(1,M-N)]; N = M;
else
    NM = 0;
end

%

K = floor(N/2); B = zeros(K,3); A = zeros(K,3);
if K*2 == N;
    b = [b 0];
    a = [a 0];
end

%

broots = cplxpair(roots(b));
aroots = cplxpair(roots(a));

for i=1:2:2*K

    Brow = broots(i:1:i+1,:);
    Brow = real(poly(Brow));

    B(fix((i+1)/2),:) = Brow;

    Arow = aroots(i:1:i+1,:);
    Arow = real(poly(Arow));

    A(fix((i+1)/2),:) = Arow;

end
```

`dir2cas.m`:

```
function [SOS,G] = zp2sos(z,p,k,DoNotCombineReal)

  if nargin<3, k=1; endif
  if nargin<2, p=[]; endif

  DoNotCombineReal = 1;

  [zc, zr] = cplxreal (z(:));
  [pc, pr] = cplxreal (p(:));

  nzc = length (zc);
  npc = length (pc);

  nzr = length (zr);
  npr = length (pr);

  if DoNotCombineReal

    # Handling complex conjugate poles
    for count = 1:npc
      SOS(count, 4:6) = [1, -2 * real(pc(count)), abs(pc(count))^2];
    endfor

    # Handling real poles
    for count = 1:npr
      SOS(count + npc, 4:6) = [0, 1, -pr(count)];
    endfor

    # Handling complex conjugate zeros
    for count = 1:nzc
      SOS(count, 1:3) = [1, -2 * real(zc(count)), abs(zc(count))^2];
    endfor

    # Handling real zeros
    for count = 1:nzr
      SOS(count+nzc, 1:3) = [0, 1, -zr(count)];
    endfor

    # Completing SOS if needed (sections without pole or zero)
    if npc + npr > nzc + nzr
      for count = nzc + nzr + 1 : npc + npr % sections without zero
        SOS(count, 1:3) = [0, 0, 1];
      end
    else
      for count = npc + npr + 1 : nzc + nzr % sections without pole
        SOS(count, 4:6) = [0, 0, 1];
      endfor
    endif

  else

    # Handling complex conjugate poles
    for count = 1:npc
      SOS(count, 4:6) = [1, -2 * real(pc(count)), abs(pc(count))^2];
    endfor

    # Handling pair of real poles
    for count = 1:floor(npr/2)
       SOS(count+npc, 4:6) = [1, - pr(2 * count - 1) - pr(2 * count), pr(2 * count - 1) * pr(2 * count)];
    endfor

    # Handling last real pole (if any)
    if mod (npr,2) == 1
      SOS(npc + floor (npr / 2) + 1, 4:6)= [0, 1, -pr(end)];
    endif


    # Handling complex conjugate zeros
    for count = 1:nzc
      SOS(count, 1:3)= [1, -2 * real(zc(count)), abs(zc(count))^2];
    endfor

    # Handling pair of real zeros
    for count = 1:floor(nzr / 2)
       SOS(count+nzc, 1:3)= [1, - zr(2 * count - 1) - zr(2 * count), zr(2 * count - 1) * zr(2 * count)];
    endfor

    # Handling last real zero (if any)
    if mod (nzr, 2) == 1
      SOS(nzc + floor (nzr / 2) + 1, 1:3) = [0, 1, -zr(end)];
    endif

    # Completing SOS if needed (sections without pole or zero)
    if npc + ceil(npr / 2) > nzc + ceil(nzr / 2)
      for count = nzc + ceil (nzr / 2) + 1 : npc + ceil (npr / 2) % sections without zero
        SOS(count, 1:3) = [0, 0, 1];
      endfor
    else
      for count = npc + ceil(npr / 2) + 1:nzc + ceil (nzr / 2) % sections without pole
        SOS(count, 4:6) = [0, 0, 1];
      endfor
    endif
  endif

  if ~exist ('SOS')
    SOS=[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1];
  endif

  ## If no output argument for the overall gain, combine it into the
  ## first section.
  if (nargout < 2)
    SOS(1,1:3) = k * SOS(1,1:3);
  else
    G = k;
  endif
```

Comment: Which one gives equal responses against the original?

Comment: @JuhaP What is original(Do you mean original TF?), and what do you mean from equal response?

Comment: yes, the TF which uses those nth order coefficients you split then to second order sections ... i.e. does resulting sos or cas filter produce equal responses as what the nth order filter produces (as you mention different response between sos and cas methods).

Comment: @juha Note that that response means octave prompt response, not frequency response.

Answer (score 2):

Converting an arbitrary transfer function to second order sections involves factoring the assumed longer numerator and denominator polynomials into second order polynomials. By cascading second order sections in series, the individual 2nd order polynomials for each are multiplied to result in the original higher order numerator and denominator polynomials.

That said both are probably correct, and that can be confirmed just by convolving the 2nd order coefficients (which is how polynomial multiplication is done).

There are many ways to factor the polynomials (basically select the pairs of complex poles and zeros from the set of all poles and zeros associated with the original transfer function), so there can be many different solutions. Which are chosen can have a significant impact on noise especially when the implementation is done with fixed point; strategically for that purpose it is better to group the poles and zeros together that have similar radius from the origin: I have a paper on this that I will link in a later update to this answer.

Comment: "Which are chosen can have a significant impact on noise especially when the implementation is done with fixed point."  Or if you've misplaced the "D" in DSP and are implementing a filter with op-amps, resistors and capacitors.

Comment: @TimWescott great point, I shouldn’t have assumed the “D”! Still we have the same considerations and same noise enhancements / gains from poorly designed IIR sections, just instead of white quantization noise we have the noise density of the op amp outputs.

Comment: Totally different mechanisms, same result...